# Accessing nested JSON values with unknown names in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How do I access values in a nested JSON if the value names are not know to me in advance.

I.e. in the JSON below I need to access the names of the confectionery options to add them to a SQLite table. But the types of confectionery as well as their each confectionery option names aren't know to me in advance.

A sample of the JSON may look like this, where there can be any number of confectionery options, each with its own number of options.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "sweet": "sweets",
    "sweets": 
    [{
        "idsweets": "1",
        "sweetsdesc": "Choocolate Chip"
    }, {
        "idsweets": "2",
        "sweetsdesc": "Mint"
    }],
    "drink": "drinks",
    "drinks": 
    [{
        "iddrinks": "1",
        "drinksdesc": "Coke"
    }, {
        "iddrinks": "2",
        "drinksdesc": "Pepsi"
    }, {
        "iddrinks": "3",
        "drinksdesc": "Fanta"
    }, {
        "iddrinks": "4",
        "drinksdesc": "Dr. Pepper"
    }, {
        "iddrinks": "5",
        "drinksdesc": "Powerade"
    }],
    "crisp": "crisps",
    "crisps": 
    [{
        "idcrisps": "1",
        "crispsdesc": "Salt"
    }, {
        "idcrisps": "2",
        "crispsdesc": "Vinegar"
    }, {
        "idcrisps": "3",
        "crispsdesc": "Cheese and Onion"
    }, {
        "idcrisps": "4",
        "crispsdesc": "Pepper"
    }, {
        "idcrisps": "5",
        "crispsdesc": "Chilli"
    }, {
        "idcrisps": "6",
        "crispsdesc": "Other"
    }]
}]
```

To insert each confectionery option into the Database I try the following, but with no luck.

```
function goInsertValueOptionsList()
{
    db.transaction(insertValueOptionsList, errorCB, successCB);
}

function insertValueOptionsList(tx)
{
    angular.forEach($scope.optionValuesAPIData, function (value, key) // A variable to hold the confectionary JSON
    {
        alert("Value Options - Value: " + value); // Prints the JSON [object Object]

        for (var description in value)
        {
            // Get the Column name
            alert("Value Options - Description (Column name): " + description);
            // Get the Column value
            alert("Value Options - Description (Column Value): " + value[description]);

            // Inner loop for nested JSON objects
            angular.forEach(value, function (v, k)
            {
                // Get the Column name - try to access e.g. idcrisps
                alert("V Options - Description (Column name): " + v); // Not working
                // Get the Column value
                alert("V Options - Description (Column Value): " + k); // Not working

                // Use v and k to insert into database
            });
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: I would first wonder why the non-standard property names. Is this something you control? Whole structure isn't very friendly at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at what you provided you can traverse all of these objects with code like this:

```
data.forEach(function(dataset) // A variable to hold the confectionary JSON
{

    Object.keys(dataset).forEach(function(key) 
    {

        // Inner loop for nested JSON objects
        if(Array.isArray(dataset[key])) {
          dataset[key].forEach(function(item)
          {
              console.log(item)

              // Use v and k to insert into database
          });
        } else {
          console.log(dataset[key])
        }

    })

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4x4uKOqmqxZcDS2DPgPM?p=preview

Comment: check console, its all there for me